# exit status 1 'class WiFiClass' has no member named "softAP" in NodeMCU

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266, nodemcu

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

 
#define LED_BUILTIN 2   // Set the GPIO pin where you connected your test LED or comment this line out if your dev board has a built-in LED
 
// Set these to your desired credentials.
const char *ssid = "OptimusCrime";
const char *password = "01679044306";
 
WiFiServer server(80);
 
 
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Configuring access point...");
 
  // You can remove the password parameter if you want the AP to be open.
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);
  server.begin();
 
  Serial.println("Server started");
}
 
void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // listen for incoming clients
 
  if (client) {                             // if you get a client,
    Serial.println("New Client.");           // print a message out the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
 
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println();
 
            // the content of the HTTP response follows the header:
            client.print("Click <a href=\"/H\">here</a> to turn ON the LED.<br>");
            client.print("Click <a href=\"/L\">here</a> to turn OFF the LED.<br>");
 
            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line:
            client.println();
            // break out of the while loop:
            break;
          } else {    // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
 
        // Check to see if the client request was "GET /H" or "GET /L":
        if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /H")) {
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);               // GET /H turns the LED on
        }
        if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /L")) {
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);                // GET /L turns the LED off
        }
      }
    }
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client Disconnected.");
  }
}
```

The error is (exit status 1 'class WiFiClass' has no member named "softAP")
I so don't know why this is happening with only me, pls helppp(Bunch of random word so it does not say "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details" : aifnalvnalinflajsfnlavnaknlinfe)
Anyways thanks for reviewing by problem

Comment: `#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>`

Answer (score 2):

If you're building this for an ESP8266 you're using the incorrect header filenames.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
```

should be

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
```

The [examples in the ESP8266 Arduino Core repo](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples) will show you more code that is correctly using this ESP8266 wifi library.